# How to unify logs from different sources?

Tags: python, logging

I want my web app to write all logs in single uniform format. There are several plugged modules and **gunicorn** besides that have their own handlers with own format.

I figured out how to drop the handlers from all existing loggers except root and to propagate all messages to root. It works, but I don't suspect it's not the best way. Are there better ways to do this?

```
logging.basicConfig(
  handlers=[my_handler],
  level=log_level,
)

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
for _, logger in root_logger.manager.loggerDict.items():
  logger.handlers = []
  logger.propagate = True
```

Comment: Only very bad modules define handlers that actually do something. They are only supposed to have loggers, and it's up to the user to add handlers.

Comment: Then gunicorn is a very bad module https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/cf55d2cec277f220ebd605989ce78ad1bb553c46/gunicorn/glogging.py#L63

Comment: Is it a good practice to remove handlers in such a way as @xneg introduces in the case of "very bad modules"?